# Why does CGColor.copy() return an optional value?

Tags: swift, option-type, cgcolor

So since the function `CGColor.copy()` returns an optional value, one would assume that there might be a reason for it to return nil. However I cannot think of any reason for this to fail other than if the CGColor itself is an optional value. Since I am using this in my program does anyone know a reason for this to return nil on a value that is not optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've explained it correctly. Remember, there is really no such object as a CGColor; it doesn't actually have methods like `copy`. This is a hand-tweaked rendering of a global C function:

```
CGColorRef CGColorCreateCopy(CGColorRef color);
```

Well, a CGColorRef can always be `nil`, so `color` can be `nil`, so the result can be `nil`. So the result has to be an Optional. (It can't be sometimes an Optional and at other times not an Optional.)